# scrollTop jQuery not working :/

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have trouble with function scrollTop. I try set scroll to #comment when .scrollToComment was clicked but dunno why its not working...

head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1"></script>
```

and code for scroll:

```
$(".scrollToComment").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#comment").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
```

problem is on my starting new little project:
http://katalogliquidow.mrqzi.webd.pl/

pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace your code for scroll**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.scrollToComment',function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#comment").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

It work fine for me

Cheers